# Why is :focus overriding :focus-visible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've got an issue with `:focus-visible` and Bootstrap. The project I'm working on uses Bootstrap which has `button:focus:not(:focus-visible)` and `button:focus:not(.focus-visible)` for buttons. In my css I've got:

```scss
button {
  &:focus-visible {
     outline: var(--outline-size) var(--outline-style) var(--outline-color);
  }
}
```

but my `:focus-visible` is not shown. When I inspect the button and do Force element state:focus it shows (as expected):

```css
button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}
button:focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: 0; //crossed out
}
```

and when I do Force element state:focus-visible, i get my style for :focus-visible. However, when I tab to the button, `:focus-visible` is not shown. If I uncheck `button:focus:not(.focus-visible)` in dev tools, `:focus-visible` is shown on tab. As far as I know `:focus` should not override `:focus-visible`, so what am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell what might be going wrong, from just those mere snippets. Please create a proper [mre] of the issue, so that we can inspect it ourselves.

Comment: Basically, this is what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/eaL3vrmf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, this is what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/eaL3vrmf/

```css
button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

/* The :focus-visible works if this is removed */
button:focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

button:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px dashed hotpink;
}
```

```html
Test: <button>I am a button</button>
```

Okay, a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue then. `button:focus:not(.focus-visible)` has specificity `0-2-1`, whereas your `button:focus-visible` only has `0-1-1` (https://specificity.keegan.st) So you need to increase the specificity of your own selector (unless you wanted to use the jucky `!important`) One easy way to get your selector to the same specificity as the existing one, is to add a class selector - or a `:not()` with a nonsense class the button will never get in reality.

```css
button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

/* The :focus-visible works if this is removed */
button:focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: 0;
}

button:not(.never-ever-gonna-be-set):focus-visible {
  outline: 2px dashed hotpink;
}
```

```html
Test:
<button>I am a button</button>
```

That will work, if your rule comes after the existing ones from the framework - because both selectors have the same specificity now. If that order was not the case, then you would need to increase the specificity of your own one even more.

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected it was a specifity issue but I didn´t see it until your explanation. I tried .button:focus-visible but obviously that did not work and I want to avoid !important as much as possible. Didn't think of :not() with a nonsense class, brilliant! And thank you for the detailed explanation!